# Extracting time multiplier from time limit in mute command [ Solved ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a `mute` command and I want it to be able to take time limit with space and without space both. So what I wanted to do is that I wanted to take the `timelimit` and make two parts of it one `int` and another one `str` in the `str` part I will check the first two alphabets and check for the multiplier now it works without space but with space it takes the unit part as `reason`. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

```py
def parse_time_input(time_input: str) -> tuple[int, str]:
    match = re.match(r'(\d+)\s*([a-z]+)', time_input)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1)), match.group(2)
    else:
        match = re.match(r'(\d+)', time_input)
        if match:
            return int(match.group(1)), "s"
        else:
            return -1, ""

@bot.command(aliases=["shut", "zip"])
async def mute(ctx, member: Union[discord.Member, int], timelimit: str = '28d', *, reason: str = "No reason provided"):
    if isinstance(member, int):
        member = await bot.fetch_user(member)
    elif isinstance(member, str):
        member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name=member)

    time_value, time_unit = parse_time_input(timelimit.lower())

    if time_value == -1:
        await ctx.send("<:error:1131175466049470505> | Invalid time format")
        return

    unit_multipliers = {
        's': 1,
        'sec': 1,
        'secs': 1,
        'second': 1,
        'seconds': 1,
        'm': 60,
        'min': 60,
        'mins': 60,
        'minute': 60,
        'minutes': 60,
        'h': 3600,
        'hour': 3600,
        'hours': 3600,
        'd': 86400,
        'day': 86400,
        'days': 86400,
        'w': 604800,
        'week': 604800,
        'weeks': 604800,
    }

    multiplier = unit_multipliers.get(time_unit, 1)
    total_seconds = time_value * multiplier
    mute_time = timedelta(seconds=total_seconds)

    if mute_time.total_seconds() > 2419200:
        await ctx.send("<:error:1131175466049470505> | Timeout limit can't be over 28 days!")
        return

    await member.edit(timed_out_until=discord.utils.utcnow() + mute_time)

    await ctx.send(f"<:check:1132263275770429471> | {member.mention} has been muted for {mute_time} by {ctx.author.mention}\nReason: {reason}")

# My mute logging part
```

#### I posted the solved code below

Comment: The easiest "fix" would be to wrap the time in quotes when invoking the command, for example: `!mute @Some_member "12 hours" your reason here`. Otherwise you would have to do some fairly complicated parsing. Not really a great solution though so just posting as a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @moinierer3000 your solution will work I think but I want it to be easy for moderators to remember. Some bots like Dyno, Carl do support this thing so I thought I will also be able to make something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately Dyno and Carl aren't open source (anymore) as far as I know, but the creator of discord.py has a bot who also does the same thing you want to achieve. You can look into how he does it [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/rewrite/cogs/utils/time.py). As I said though, requires some fairly complicated parsing.

Comment: Yeah I found an outdated (repo)[https://github.com/CarlGroth/Carl-Bot] but not the current one, and thanks for the link I will try to find my solution from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

I found a way of doing it, but it's kind of different then what I did previously.

Thanks to anyone who tried to help me. I will leave this code here if anyone wants they can use it.

### Explanation

What I did here is I took the `timelimit` variable and checked if there is time unit in it if not then I will check the next part [ which is in `reason` part ] then check for the first part of `reason` to get the `time_unit`. After that for logging I will use the `remove_unit` function to remove the unit part from the reason and if it was in the `timelimit` var then we can just directly use it.

**Sorry but my explanation is not that good, hope you will understand it**

```py
def extract_time_parts(time_input: str) -> tuple[str, str]:
    match = re.match(r'(\d+)\s*([a-z]+)', time_input)
    if match:
        return match.group(1), match.group(2)
    
    match = re.match(r'(\d+)([a-z]+)', time_input, re.IGNORECASE)
    if match:
        return match.group(1), match.group(2)
    
    return "", ""

def remove_unit(input_str):
    words = input_str.split()
    if len(words) > 1:
        return ' '.join(words[1:])
    
    return ''

@bot.command(aliases=["shut", "zip"])
async def mute(ctx, member: commands.MemberConverter, timelimit: str = '28d', *, reason: str = None):
    if isinstance(member, int):
        member = await bot.fetch_user(member)
    
    time_value, time_unit = extract_time_parts(timelimit)
    time_unit = time_unit[:1]
    main_reason = reason
    
    if not time_value or not time_unit:
        time_value = timelimit
        
        if reason and reason[0].lower() in ['s', 'm', 'h', 'd', 'w']:
            time_unit = reason[0].lower()
            reason = reason[1:].strip()
            
            reason_with_unit = reason
            main_reason = remove_unit(reason_with_unit)
            
            if main_reason == "":
                main_reason = "No reason provided"
            
        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid time format | `?mute @user 5s reason`")
            return
    
    unit_multipliers = {
        's': 1,
        'm': 60,
        'h': 3600,
        'd': 86400,
        'w': 604800
    }
    
    multiplier = unit_multipliers.get(time_unit, 1)
    mute_time = timedelta(seconds=int(time_value) * multiplier)
    
    if mute_time.total_seconds() > 2419200:
        await ctx.send("Timeout limit can't be over 28 days!")
        return
    
    await member.edit(timed_out_until=discord.utils.utcnow() + mute_time)
    
    if reason is None:
        reason = "No reason provided"
    
    if time_unit == 's':
        log_unit = 'second(s)'
    
    elif time_unit == 'm':
        log_unit = 'minute(s)'
        
    elif time_unit == 'h':
        log_unit = 'hour(s)'
        
    elif time_unit == 'd':
        log_unit = 'day(s)'
        
    elif time_unit == 'w':
        log_unit = 'week(s)'
    
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been muted for {time_value} {log_unit} by {ctx.author.mention}\nReason: {main_reason}")
    
# Your logging part
```